# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for an array I didn't declare the size of. What do I do?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```java
String[] splittedData = data.split("\\s+");
             
answerString = data + " :";

answerString = answerString +
    wordChecker.imperfectPalindrome(splittedData[0]);

answerString = answerString + 
    wordChecker.imperfectPalindrome(splittedData[1]);

answerString = answerString +
    wordChecker.superAnagrams(splittedData[0], splittedData[1]);
```

for `splittedData[1]`, IDE throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Is this because of some mistake in array declaration or is this something else?

Comment: The IDE did not throw it

Answer (score 2):

Your `splittedData` array will take the exact required length to store the results of the `.split`. If entered `data` doesn't contain any space, then `splittedData` will have length 1. If entered `data` is empty, then it will have length 0.

So if after that you try and access `splittedData[1]`, then the index will indeed be out of bounds

***Clarification***

In Java, array indices are from 0 (inclusive) to array length (exclusive)

Comment: Thank you. Well in that case I should use something other than `.split` because my `data` has a single space in each line. Any suggestions on how I might not exceed the index out of bounds for such `data`?

Comment: If you want to "cut" at space, then `.split` is exactly the operation you need (you can set a limit of 2 just in case there could be 2 spaces one day). then you can either copy the results to a fixed-size array of length 2, or test `if (splittedData.length > 1)` before accessing `splittedData[1]`